# <form target=...> пытается открыться во всплывающем окне в Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, кроссбраузерность

Firefox почему-то считает, что iframe это всплывающее окно и запрещает его. Тем самым, `$('#submit').click()` не срабатывает. Сверху появляется жёлтая полоска, где написано, мол разрешить или нет? Нажимаю "разрешить" и в итоге вместо того, чтобы получить ответ во фрейме, меня тупо перенаправляет на /upload.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" target="test">
 <input onchange="$('#submit').click()" type="file" name="file">
 <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
<iframe id="test"></iframe>
```

Comment: @ModaL, а зачем вам iframe? Если только для фоновой подгрузки контента, то выбросьте его и используйте AJAX.

Comment: @fori1ton, как хотите, но нужен iframe. В том же ВК на iframe работает ок. У меня беда только в firefox.

Comment: Проблему решил сам. Оказывается нужно было фрейму прописать name="test"

Comment: Из описания, данного в вопросе совершенно непонятно, что оказывается нужно было сделать отправку формы в iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переношу из комментария: target=... в `<form>` должен соответствовать атрибуту `name=...`, а не `id=...` в iframe.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe